# Java vs. C#: BigInteger hex string yields different result?

Tags: java, c#, arrays, biginteger, endianness

Question:

This code in Java:

```
BigInteger mod = new BigInteger("86f71688cdd2612ca117d1f54bdae029", 16);
```

produces (in java) the number

```
179399505810976971998364784462504058921
```

However, when I use C#,

```
BigInteger mod = BigInteger.Parse("86f71688cdd2612ca117d1f54bdae029", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber); // base 16
```

i don't get the same number, I get:

```
-160882861109961491465009822969264152535
```

However, when I create the number directly from decimal, it works

```
BigInteger mod = BigInteger.Parse("179399505810976971998364784462504058921");
```

I tried converting the hex string in a byte array and reversing it, and creating a biginteger from the reversed array, just in case it's a byte array with different endianness, but that didn't help...

I also encountered the following problem when converting Java-Code to C#:
Java

```
BigInteger k0 = new BigInteger(byte[]);
```

to get the same number in C#, I must reverse the array because of different Endianness in the biginteger implementation

C# equivalent:

```
BigInteger k0 = new BigInteger(byte[].Reverse().ToArray());
```

Comment: Try adding a zero before the 8 in your C# version.

Comment: @RealSkeptic that should be an answer; works for me [here](http://ideone.com/w3Ee5H).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what MSDN says about [`BigInteger.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268285.aspx):

> If value is a hexadecimal string, the `Parse(String, NumberStyles)` method interprets value as a negative number stored by using two's complement representation if its first two hexadecimal digits are greater than or equal to **0x80**. In other words, the method interprets the highest-order bit of the first byte in value as the sign bit. To make sure that a hexadecimal string is correctly interpreted as a positive number, the first digit in value must have a value of zero. For example, the method interprets **0x80** as a negative value, but it interprets either **0x080** or **0x0080** as a positive value.

So, add a `0` in front of the parsed hexadecimal number to force an unsigned interpretation.

As for round-tripping a big integer represented by a byte array between Java and C#, I'd advise against that, unless you really have to. But both implementations *happen* to use a compatible two's complement representation, if you fix the endianness issue.

[MSDN says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.tobytearray.aspx):

> The individual bytes in the array returned by this method appear in **little-endian** order. That is, the lower-order bytes of the value precede the higher-order bytes. The first byte of the array reflects the first eight bits of the `BigInteger` value, the second byte reflects the next eight bits, and so on.

[Java docs say](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray--):

> Returns a byte array containing the two's-complement representation of this `BigInteger`. The byte array will be in **big-endian** byte-order: the most significant byte is in the zeroth element.