# Why do C# and Java BigInteger convert byte[] differently?

Tags: java, c#, biginteger

This is Java code:

```
new BigInteger("abc".getBytes()).toString();
```

and the result is **6382179**.

I want the same result in C# but when I use the following code:

```
(new System.Numerics.BigInteger(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abc"))).ToString();
```

I get **6513249**.

How do I convert the string in C# the same way as Java?

Comment: I reopened this question because I think the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32413108/java-vs-c-biginteger-hex-string-yields-different-result) asks about a pair of totally different API that just so happens to also have the little/big endianness problem. It is only related, but not a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C#'s [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Numerics_BigInteger__ctor_System_Byte___) treats the byte array as little-endian:

> **Parameters**
>
> value `Byte[]`
>
> An array of byte values in little-endian order.

Whereas Java's [`BigInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger(byte%5B%5D)) treats the byte array as big-endian:

> Translates a byte array containing the two's-complement binary representation of a BigInteger into a BigInteger. The input array is assumed to be in big-endian byte-order: the most significant byte is in the zeroth element.

So you need to [reverse the byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893758/how-to-reverse-the-byte-array-in-java) to get the same result as you do in the other language.

Also note that Java's `String.getBytes` uses the default encoding, which might not be ASCII. You should use

```
StandardCharsets.US_ASCII.encode("abc").array()
// or
"abc".getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)
```

to get the same set of bytes as the C# code.